# Can't write "#" symbol in VS Code on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, all characters and symbols work without problems except #. I tried all keyboard keys, SHIFT+3 OPTION+3 etc.; none work, the problem is only with VS Code. No other programs have problems; please take a look at this short [video](https://youtu.be/nuQLyTeVsKw).

I'm new to macOS; previously I had no problems with Windows.

Mac model: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) | UK keyboard layout (ISO keyboard) | input sources include British, Arabic, Sorani Kuridish

Screenshot from video…

[image]

Comment: Try pressing the \ key.  PC British layouts have # there.

Comment: @TomGewecke It didn't work

Comment: Please let us know by updating your question what model Mac you are using and what country keyboard your Mac has, and what is currently set in `System Preferences | Keyboard | Input Sources`. Documenting the problem in a video obscures it from others who might want to search for the same combination of factors. Also it ensures the question remains valid, as the video may disappear in the future.

Comment: I inlined a still from the video. Keyboard looks like UK English to me.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Sorry for the late replay, I added what you said

Comment: I changed your ANSI to ISO, since your picture is clearly ISO with the vertical return key and extra key next to the short left shift.  Let us know if you really do have ANSI with the horizontal return and longer left shift.

Comment: @TomGewecke Sorry I added the information by mistake, I only Have ISO keyboard, my bad

Comment: Are you seeing this problem when editing in a specific language, eg Python, JS, such that there might be some VSCode extensions in use? Can you reproduce the problem when editing a plain old text file?